# Apply back folder links in Urls

Tags: c#

I have an url that i have to put together from some parsed data.
Example:

```
http://www.example.com/en/structures-list/../toscana/cortona-and-valdichiana/villas-with-pool/casale-aiola/casale-aiola/../../../../../../public/imgCase/img/R15421-Am.jpg
```

This is a valid URL, but if you apply all the ../ will the url become

```
http://www.example.com/public/imgCase/img/R15421-Am.jpg
```

Are there a quick way to do this in C#?

Comment: Where do you apply them?

Comment: ../ means one directory up, so http://www.example.com/en/structures-list/../ is the same as http://www.example.com/en/

Comment: I know that resolving the path results in this but what code component performs this resolution of ..\ ? Do you call Process.Start(url), or are you creating an Uri class with that?

Comment: URI are not supported by Path

Comment: You cannot put the thing above into a Path as it is not a valid path but an Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest way is:

```
new Uri("%YourUrl%).AbsoluteUri
```